# Which `boost::system::error_code` value should be provided when `boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::resolve()` fails?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I want to return a `boost::system::error_code` indicationg whether a host/service could be resolved or not. There might be multiple reasons why a host/service look-up failed (e.g. network connection problems or an invalid argument).

What should be returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible to get this right from outside `resolve()`.  But you can get it to do it for you, by using one of the overloads that takes an `error_code&` as an out-parameter:

- [`iterator resolve(const query & q, boost::system::error_code & ec)`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__basic_resolver/resolve/overload2.html)
- [`iterator resolve(const endpoint_type & e, boost::system::error_code & ec)`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__basic_resolver/resolve/overload4.html)

and then return the error_code it sets.  I trust that this will wrap up [`errno`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/errno.html) or [`h_errno`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/h_errno.html) as appropriate.

Answer (score 5):

You have to come up with error code and category in order to create `error_code` object. Here is an example, assuming that error is due to another host refusing connection:

```
error_code ec (errc::connection_refused, system_category());
return ec;
```

You can also pass `errno` value as error code when using system category. For example:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <cerrno>
#include <boost/system/system_error.hpp>

void foo ()
{
    ifstream file ("test.txt");
    if (!file.is_open ())
    {
        int err_code = errno;
        boost::system::error_code ec (err_code
            , boost::system::system_category ());
        throw boost::system::system_error (ec, "cannot open file");
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this library is poorly [documented](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/system/doc/index.html), so I can recommend you to look into [header files](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/boost/system/) to figure things out. The code is fairly simple and straight forward there.

Just in case your compiler supports C++11 and you are willing to use it, this functionality made it into standard. As far as I know gcc 4.6.1 has it already. Here is a simple example:

```
#include <cerrno>
#include <system_error>

std::error_code
SystemError::getLastError ()
{
    int err_code = errno;
    return std::error_code (err_code, std::system_category ());
}

void foo ()
{
    throw std::system_error (getLastError (), "something went wrong");
}
```

Generally, libraries pass `error_code` object around if there is no need to throw and use `system_error` to throw an exception describing system failures. Another reason to use `error_code` without exceptions is when you need to signal the error across different threads. But C++11 has [a solution for propagating exceptions across threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233127/how-can-i-propagate-exceptions-between-threads).

Hope it helps!