# Will main() catch exceptions thrown from threads?

Tags: c++, exception, pthreads

I have a pretty large application that dynamically loads shared objects and executes code in the shared object. As a precaution, I put a try/catch around almost everything in `main`. I created a catch for 3 things: `myException` (an in house exception), `std::exception`, and `...` (catch all exceptions).

As part of the shared objects execution, many `pthreads` are created. When a thread throws an exception, it is not caught by `main`. Is this the standard behavior? How can I catch all exceptions, no matter what thread they are thrown from?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

> Will main() catch exceptions thrown from threads?

No

> When a thread throws an exception, it is not caught by main. Is this the standard behavior?

Yes, this is standard behaviour.

To catch an exception originating in thread `X`, you have to have the `try`-`catch` clause in thread `X` (for example, around everything in the thread function, similarly to what you already do in `main`).

For a related question, see [How can I propagate exceptions between threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233127/how-can-i-propagate-exceptions-between-threads)

Answer (score 27):

Your question is asking for something that isn't conceptually possible.

Try blocks are defined as dynamic constructs of the stack. A try block catches exceptions thrown by code reached dynamically, by call, from its contents.

When you create a new thread, you create a brand-new stack, that is not at all part of the dynamic context of the try block, even if the call to pthread_create is inside the try.

Answer (score 10):

No, main will not catch exceptions thrown from other threads.  You would need to use a non-standard, platform specific facility that addresses unhandled exceptions in order to aggregate the handling the way you are describing.

When I build such applications, I make sure each active object has its own top-level exception handling block, precisely to prevent the entire application from exploding if one thread fails.  Using a platform-specific catch all I think begs for your overall code / solution to be sloppy.  I would not use such a thing.

Answer (score 8):

Consider that throwing an exception unwinds the stack. Each thread has its own stack. You will have to place a try/catch block in each thread function (i.e. in the entry point of each thread).