# boost::asio::co_spawn does not propagate exception

Tags: c++, exception, boost, coroutine

I'm dabbling in coroutines in respect to boost::asio, and I'm confused by exception handling.  Judging by the [examples](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp17/coroutines_ts/chat_server.cpp) [in](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp17/coroutines_ts/echo_server.cpp) the docs, it looks like any 'fail' `error_code` is turned into an exception - so I *hopefully assumed* that any exception thrown would also be propagated back to the `co_spawn` call.  But that doesn't appear to be case:

```
#define BOOST_ASIO_HAS_CO_AWAIT
#define BOOST_ASIO_HAS_STD_COROUTINE

#include <iostream>

#include <boost/asio/awaitable.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/co_spawn.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/detached.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/io_context.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/executor_work_guard.hpp>

namespace this_coro = boost::asio::this_coro;

boost::asio::awaitable<void> async_op()
{
    std::cout << "About to throw" << std::endl;
    throw std::runtime_error{"Bang!"};
}

int main()
{
    auto ctx = boost::asio::io_context{};
    auto guard = boost::asio::make_work_guard(ctx.get_executor());

    boost::asio::co_spawn(ctx, async_op, boost::asio::detached);

    ctx.run();
}
```

If this is ran in a debugger, you can see the exception being thrown, but then it just seems to hang.  Pausing the debugger shows that the `ctx.run()` is waiting for new work (due to the `executor_work_guard`).  So it looks like something inside boost::asio has silently swallowed the exception.

As an experiment, I switched the async operation to use boost::asio library calls:

```
boost::asio::awaitable<void> async_op()
{
    auto executor = co_await this_coro::executor;
    auto socket = boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket{executor};

    std::cout << "Starting resolve" << std::endl;
    auto resolver = boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver{executor};
    const auto endpoints = co_await resolver.async_resolve("localhost",
                                                           "4444",
                                                           boost::asio::use_awaitable);



    std::cout << "Starting connect (num endpoints: " << endpoints.size() << ")" << std::endl;
    co_await boost::asio::async_connect(socket, endpoints, boost::asio::use_awaitable);
    std::cout << "Exited" << std::endl;
}
```

I don't have a server running on port 4444, so this should fail immediately - and it does but silently.  Pausing the debugger shows that it's stuck in epoll waiting for something (I'm on Linux).

Swapping the `async_connect` `CompletionToken` to a `boost::asio::redirect_error` shows that the operation is failing:

```
co_await boost::asio::async_connect(socket,
                                    endpoints, 
                                    boost::asio::redirect_error(boost::asio::use_awaitable, ec));
std::cout << "Exited: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
```

Yields:

```
Starting resolve
Starting connect (num endpoints: 1)
Exited: Connection refused
```

So how do I propagate exceptions, and create them from `error_code`s, out of coroutines in boost::asio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`boost::asio::co_spawn` creates a [separate thread](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/co_spawn.html). This means that exceptions are not propagated. You can read more about this here:

- [Will main() catch exceptions thrown from threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7730502/will-main-catch-exceptions-thrown-from-threads)
- [How can I propagate exceptions between threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233127/how-can-i-propagate-exceptions-between-threads)

But `co_spawn` supports a completion handler with the signature `void(std::exception_ptr, R)`. In your example you used `boost::asio::detached` which means the completion result is ignored. To propagate it simply [write a custom handler](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/co_spawn/overload1.html).

Comment: I was wondering how I missed the `CompletionToken` callback signature for `co_spawn`, but it was because I was looking at the v1.71 docs which doesn't have the examples.  Thank you very much, it works as expected now.

Comment: While the solution is correct, the reasoning is not: `asio::co_spawn` actually doesn't "create a separate thread" but a thread of execution which runs on the executor specified. In OP's examples the executor is run on the same thread, so the coroutine is as well. The implementation of `asio::co_spawn` simply catches all thrown errors and passes them as `std::exception_ptr` into the completion handler. `asio::detached` just so happens to not do anything with the exception.

Comment: also don't quite like the way to abuse the word thread in async world, so confusing.