# A question about c++ threads exception handling

Tags: c++, multithreading, exception

Demo code:

```cpp
#include <exception>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <thread>

void func1() {
  std::cout << "Hello func1\n";
  throw std::runtime_error("func1 error");
}

int main() {
  try {
    std::future<void> result1 = std::async(func1);
    result1.get();
  } catch (const std::exception &e) {
    std::cerr << "Error caught: " <<e.what() << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Output:

> Hello func1
> Error caught: func1 error

It seems that the main function can catch exception from thread. But based on this [question & answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7730502/will-main-catch-exceptions-thrown-from-threads) , the main function should not be able to catch thread exception. It confused me. Maybe I mis-understand some information. Could anyone give some tips? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are not catching exceptions from `thread`, you are catching them from `async`. These are two different things that work differently.

Comment: `std::future::get`: ["If an exception was stored in the shared state referenced by the future (e.g. via a call to std::promise::set_exception()) then that exception will be thrown."](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/get)

Comment: And, `std::thread`: [The return value of the top-level function is ignored and if it terminates by throwing an exception, std::terminate is called](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread), `std::async`: [if the function f returns a value or throws an exception, it is stored in the shared state accessible through the std::future that async returns to the caller](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First things first, `std::async` and `std::thread` are not the same thing at all. Moreover, `std::async` is not required to execute the callable into another thread, it depends on the [launch policy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/launch) you used.
I would suggest you to read the [documentation about `std::async`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async).

But either way, any thrown exception are already handled by `std::async` and are stored in the shared state accessible through the returned `std::future`, which means the exceptions, if any, are rethrowned when you call `std::future<T>::get()` (which happens in the main thread in your case).