# How to propagate exceptions from sub-functions in a threaded program?

Tags: c++, c++11, exception

I am trying to understand how the exceptions can be propagated between different functions and returned to main function in C++. I have a small setup:

main.cpp:

```
int run () {
.
.
try {
  testException(file);
} catch (const std::exception &e) {
    std::cerr << "Error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

test.cpp

```
std::exception_ptr g_exceptionPtr = nullptr;

void testThread() {
   std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
   .
   .
}

void testException(const std::string &file) {
  TestCSV csv(file);
  try {
    std::thread input(testThread);
    csv.writeToCSV(file, a, b, c);
    input.join();
  } catch (const std::runtime_error &e) {
      g_exceptionPtr = std::current_exception();
      std::rethrow_exception(g_exceptionPtr);
  }
}
```

In `test_csv.cpp`:

```
TestCSV::writeToCSV(const std::string &file, const std::string &a, const std::string &b, const std::string &c) {
.
.
std::ofstream outFile(file);
    if (!outFile.is_open()) {
      throw std::runtime_error("Unable to open file for writing.");
    }
}
```

Now I want to propagate the error from `writeToCSV` function and handle it in `main.cpp`. But, currently, this exception is caught in `test.cpp` but is not re-thrown to `main.cpp`.

What is the issue and how can I resolve it?

P.S: Above code is just an example and please let me know if any info is missing

Comment: just use `std::future` and `std::promise`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will main() catch exceptions thrown from threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7730502/will-main-catch-exceptions-thrown-from-threads)

Comment: You're setting `g_exceptionPtr ` in the thread, then overwriting it in the main thread.

Comment: Side note: [`std::cerr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cerr) is unit buffered, i.e., each standard stream inserter flushes the stream after it does its output. There's no need for the extra flush that `std::endl` does. Use `'\n'` to end a line unless there's a good reason not to.

Comment: @interjay, yeah that's not needed. But if I remove it also I have same behavior

Comment: `std::rethrow_exception(std::current_exception());` is simply `throw;`...

Comment: Hi @MarekR, can you please let me kow how can I use `std::future` and `std::promise` here?

Comment: @Jarod42, I tried using `throw` but I get same behavior. It's not propagated to `main.cpp`

Comment: I didn't say it is the thing to do, just the equivalence (to also better understand why it is not the correct way). (in the continuity `try { foo(); } catch(...) { throw;}` is simply `foo();`.

Comment: @Preeti what you describe is not possible for normal `try`/`catch`/`throw` behavior, the exception is not being caught elsewhere before it reaches `main`, so there is clearly another aspect at play here that you are not explaining well.  Please [edit] your question to provide a better [mcve] that actually demonstrates the real problem in action.

Comment: In case you ask for as stack trace, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/basic_stacktrace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `writeToCSV()` in the context of the same thread that is calling `run()`, so any exception that `writeToCSV()` throws and is not caught will already propagate to `run()` as expected.  You don't need to do anything extra for that.  Simply don't `catch` the exception at all, or if you do then just re-`throw` it (not `std::rethrow_exception()`).  Your usage of `std::thread` is irrelevant in this situation.

```
int run () {
  ...
  try {
    testException(file);
  } catch (const std::exception &e) {
    // this should catch whatever testException() throws...
    std::cerr << "Error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}

void testException(const std::string &file) {
  TestCSV csv(file);
  csv.writeToCSV(file, a, b, c);

  // or:

  try {
    TestCSV csv(file);
    csv.writeToCSV(file, a, b, c);
  }
  catch (const std::exception &e) {
    ...
    throw;
  }
}
```

On the other hand, if your question is about propagating exceptions across threads, then you should change your test to reflect that. Moving `writeToCSV()` into the `std::thread` would be a better test of `std::current_exception` and `std::rethrow_exception`.

`std::current_exception` allows you to capture a caught exception so you can access it outside of the `catch`.  You can capture the exception in the original thread that threw it, move it to the desired thread, and then call `std::rethrow_exception` in that thread.  In this case, after you have `join`'ed the `std::thread` if the `exception_ptr` was assigned, eg:

```
void testThread(const std::string &file, std::exception_ptr &exceptionPtr) {
  try {
    TestCSV csv(file);
    csv.writeToCSV(...);
  } catch (const std::exception &) {
    exceptionPtr = std::current_exception();
  }
}

void testException(const std::string &file) {
  std::exception_ptr exceptionPtr = nullptr;
  std::thread writer(testThread, file, std::ref(exceptionPtr));
  ...
  writer.join();
  if (exceptionPtr)
    std::rethrow_exception(exceptionPtr);
}

int run () {
  ...
  try {
    testException(file);
  } catch (const std::exception &e) {
    // this should catch whatever testThread() throws...
    std::cerr << "Error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Remy Lebeau, `csv.writeToCSV(...);` should be called inside  `testException` function. And there is no need to set `g_exceptionPtr` in `testThread`. I have updated my OP to remove this...

Comment: @Preeti The point is that whatever throws in `testThread`, you need to catch it and set `exceptionPtr` to point at `current_exception`, which you can then rethrow after `join()`ing the thread.

Comment: @Preeti the way you have presented the issue, there is no reason to use `std::current_exception()` and `std::rethrow_exception()` at all.  I have updated my answer.

Comment: Hi @RemyLebeau, thank you for the answer. One thing I wanted to add, the `testThread` is actually waiting for key press events and hence called in `testException` as part of different logic. But I also get `Debug error: abort () has been called` from your first solution

Comment: You could mention `std::promise` and `std::future` which has machinery for this.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I could, if I knew anything about them. But I don't, so I didn't

Comment: @Preeti that implies that you are throwing an exception that is not being caught.

Comment: Hi @RemyLebeau, I also tried adding `throw std::runtime_error("Testing exception.");` in `testException` inside `try` block but this is not being rethrown. Inside the `try` I need to invoke the `std::thread` as this thread will look for any key press events and this will have an affect on how `writeToCSV` function is called at different places...
But when I add `throw std::runtime_error("Testing exception.");` outside `try` (before invoking `std::thread`, this exception is caught and rethrown to main. I think the thread is forcefully terminated and this is not handled correctly...

Answer (score 0):

One approach to solves this is to use a `std::future` to deliver your results.

`std::future<T>` is an asymmetric union between a `T` and an exception.  When you call `.get()` it will throw if it holds an exception.

There are helpers to work with `std::future`, namely `std::packaged_task<R(Args...)>` and `std::promise<T>`.

Suppose you have a thread pool that operates on a queue of tasks.

First, a threadsafe queue design:

```
template<class T>
struct threadsafe_queue {
  T pop();
  std::queue<T> pop_all();
  template<class Duration>
  std::optional<T> wait_or_pop( Duration );

  void push(T);
  void push_many(std::queue<T>);
private:
  auto lock() const { return std::unique_lock{m}; }
  mutable std::mutex m;
  std::condition_variable cv;
  std::deque<T> q;
};
```

implementation left up to the reader.

Then a thread pool:

```
struct thread_pool {

  template<class F>
  auto queue_task( F f ) {
    using R = std::invoke_result_t<F&>;
    std::packaged_task<R()> t = std::forward<F>(f);
    std::future<R> f = t.get_future();
    q.push( std::packaged_task<void()>( std::move(t) );
    return f;
  }

  void start_thread( std::size_t n=1 );
private:
  threadsafe_queue<std::packaged_task<void()>> q;
  std::vector<std::thread> threads;
};
```

now you pass your tasks to the `thread_pool`.  They get run in a `packaged_task`.  If they throw, their exception is moved into the `std::future`.

To propagate the exception you just call `.get()` on the future.

Answer (score 0):

In order to catch exceptions from each of threads generated from main we need to create an array of the exception_ptr(s) matching the number of threads and then deal with the exception(s) from each thread in the main thread as shown below.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<thread>
#include<exception>
#include<stdexcept>
#include <memory>
#include <sstream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

exception_ptr eptr[10];

void f(int i)
{
    try {
        auto id = this_thread::get_id();
        cout << "Thread " << id << " sleeping ..." << '\n';
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(1));
        if(i & 1) {
          stringstream ss;
          ss << id ;
          string str ("Exception from " + ss.str());
          throw std::runtime_error(str.c_str());
        }
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        eptr[i] = current_exception();
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  thread th[10];
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(1));
    th[i] = thread(f,i);
  }

  for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    if(th[i].joinable())
      th[i].join();

    if (eptr[i]) {
      try{
            std::rethrow_exception(eptr[i]);
      }
      catch(const std::exception &ex)
      {
            std::cerr << "Thread exited with exception: " << ex.what() << "\n";
      }
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Example output:

```
$ ./excep_thread1
Thread 0xa000128e0 sleeping ...
Thread 0xa000229f0 sleeping ...
Thread 0xa00022b10 sleeping ...
Thread 0xa00022c10 sleeping ...
Thread 0xa000233a0 sleeping ...
Thread 0xa00023050 sleeping ...
Thread 0xa00023150 sleeping ...
Thread 0xa000234a0 sleeping ...
Thread 0xa000235a0 sleeping ...
Thread 0xa000236a0 sleeping ...
Thread exited with exception: Exception from 0xa000229f0
Thread exited with exception: Exception from 0xa00022c10
Thread exited with exception: Exception from 0xa00023050
Thread exited with exception: Exception from 0xa000234a0
Thread exited with exception: Exception from 0xa000236a0
```