# How to catch throws not from your thread?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, boost, error-handling

So say we have pseudocode like:

```
super_local_thread()
{
try{
throw err;
}catch(err)
{
throw err2;
}
```

and we had launched that thread with boost.
We want to chath its error with another thread. How to do such thing?

Comment: similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/233127/how-can-i-propagate-exceptions-between-threads

Comment: maybe use, `std::async` which catches your exception and then you can extract the exception out of the `std::future` object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++11 specifies a `current_exception` function (in the standard, section *18.8 Exception Handling*) to allow you to do exactly that.

Here's an MSDN article on [transporting exceptions between threads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293602.aspx) that makes use of this function.

Since you're using Boost, here's the Boost documentation for [`current_exception`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/exception/doc/current_exception.html) and Boost article on [transporting exceptions between threads](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/exception/doc/tutorial_exception_ptr.html) .

Answer (score 1):

This MSDN article may be useful

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293602.aspx

> To implement transporting exceptions, Visual C++ provides the
>   exception_ptr type and the current_exception, rethrow_exception, and
>   copy_exception functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can't; exceptions only happen on a single thread. You can have your top-level function catch all exceptions, though, and use some other mechanism to report the exception to the rest of your application.